# My Segues do not lead to different Navigation Controllers

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I'm very new to swift, so being specific would help a lot! :)

Basically, I have this code in my swift file for the TableView

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row == 1 {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("Test1", sender: self)
    }else {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("Test2", sender: self)
    }

}
```

In my storyboard, I have my Segues set up like this:
(Sorry, I don't have enough rep to post images)

Identifier: Test2, Segue: Modal.
The same thing with the other one, but with Test1 as an Identifier instead

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: The error message I get is "Thread 1, Breakpoint 1" at the first line of code I posted

Comment: Any error message? Does your app goes through your code? Do you need to send `self` (`sender`)?

Comment: Use segue "Show" as modal is depreciated.

Comment: I would like to see your Storyboard screenshot. Host it somewhere and give a link.

Comment: Sounds like you have a breakpoint set in the code and the debugger is stopping on your first line. Right click on the blue bar on the side of the code and select remove breakpoint. Or hit the play symbol on the console to continue. BTW modal is deprecated, but you can use Present Modally if modal is what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make the segue "Show" under the section "Storyboard Segue"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Modal as a segue is deprecated, use Show instead. In storyboard click on the segue (an arrow) go to Attributes inspector and click on drop down with label Segue, then select Show.

[image]